# I need help adding multiple objects with different primitive types to an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this assignment where I construct 10 objects in one class (with a constructor) then in the tester class I create 10 different objects and add them to an array:

Bike Class

1. Create a class called Bike which has only the following instance variables:

   - Number of wheels
   - Diameter of tires
   - Manufacturer name
   - Year built
2. Create the no-argument constructor
3. Create the constructor which uses all fields as parameters
4. Write the getter and setter methods for all instance variables
5. Override the toString method using the example shown above

There should be NO main method in the Bike class.

BikeTester Class

1. Create a class called BikeTester which constructs 10 different Bike objects
2. Add each Bike object to an array
3. Use a for loop to SOP each Bike reference
4. Use a second for loop to SOP only those bikes that are built after 2004 and have a wheel diameter of greater than 4

I have so far created the Bike class but am having problems in the tester class where I create the array. I'm thinking I need to use an ArrayList but I still have no clue as to how I should add the newly created objects to an array and SOP them. (Sorry if this post was a bit long I'm new to this website).

Comment: You need to create an array, not an `ArrayList`. They are not the same thing. See this tutorial: [Arrays Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this

```
Bike[] bikes = new Bike[10]; //initialize your array of 10 Bike objects
Bike bike1 = new Bike(); //initialize Bike object
bikes[0] = bike1; //bike1 is now in your array
```

With an `ArrayList` it's like this:

```
ArrayList<Bike> bikes = new ArrayList<Bike>(); //initialize your array of Bike objects
Bike bike1 = new Bike(); //initialize Bike object
bikes.add(bike1) //bike1 is now in your arraylist
```